# Browser Cookies are killing our LIVE site

Tags: session, cookie

we have a LIVE magento site from last one year.

recently we are facing very difficult problem from Browser cookies.

Frontend is not opening and keep on loading and never load.

we are using **HTTPS** for secure pages.

we are facing problem in **chrome, mozilla , opera, safari** and all other browsers.

1)If we clear the **BROWSER COOKIES**, than its working.

2)If we clear the **VAR/SESSION** folder, than its working.

3)If we open the site in freshly installed browsers, its working for some time. again same problem. as cookies will occupy after visiting site.

There is no problem in **Backend**

we followed this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491819/magento-admin-login-not-working-in-chrome-but-works-fine-for-firefox but it did't worked.

IS it related to only cookies problem or our template code problem?

[image]

we face issue as in images sometimes.[image]

[image]

Comment: you check cookie domain setting .As per as thought  it is coding issue

Comment: no, we didt check....

Comment: check  setting at mageno backedn

Comment: is i have to follow this : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/68070/whats-the-correct-cookie-config-for-a-magento-site-split-across-multiple-instan

Comment: please check image  in updated question

Comment: yes..you need to follow that

Comment: Other reason,no of files limit  is over at var/session  folder

Comment: is i have to use : Use HTTP Only : "YES" . right now we have value : "No" as in image.

Comment: we are using https for secure pages

Comment: we are using single domain site . there is no sub domain in our site , still is i have to follow this link : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/68070/whats-the-correct-cookie-config-for-a-magento-site-split-across-multiple-instan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you getting double cookies set? Bare Domain AND Subdomain? One for  `example.com` and one for `www.example.com`?

I found on our site, we needed to do an .htaccess redirect to force everything to whichever was our choice for the website base server domain or we would run afoul of session hijack as the site would respond to one, set a cookie and immediately redirect to the other. Once cookies were double-set things came to grief.

Magento's settings for Cookie Path and domain did not alleviate it, even when correctly set.

Comment: Is there any way that we can check whether we set double cookies or not ?

Comment: Look in your browser cookie store and examine the contents. Frontend and Admin cookies will be duplicated.

Comment: we dont have any sub - domain in our server for our main domain.

Comment: i am checking here : http://prntscr.com/a4sp53 

if our site name is xyz.com, than it creating cookies only for  xyz.com, its not creating cookies for www.xyz.com

than its fine right ?

Answer (score 1):

We experienced a very similar issue pages were loading blank for very specific sessions, it was almost impossible to recreated in local environments. It turned out to be an infinite loop caused by the `trigger_recollect` attribute on the carts (quotes) of these sessions. See this thread for more info:

[Customer stuck in an endless loop](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131978/customer-stuck-in-an-endless-loop/170191#170191)