# Customer stuck in an endless loop

Tags: magento-community, quote, ce-1.9.2.4, onestepcheckout

**Problem:** Some Customer (< 0.5%) got stuck in an endless loop if they visit our Shop (v1.9.2.4) or add a Product to cart. If the Customer delete the Cookies, everything works fine.

Because I can't reproduce the Problem on my local Maschine, I wrote a Script which do a curl Requests with every single session_id and log all 5xx errors.
With this Method I got a couple "bad" sessions and trace down a loop with xdebug. I figured out, that the endless loop appears if the flag `sales_flat_quote`.`trigger_recollect` is set to 1.

> app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php:1375

```
protected function _afterLoad()
{
    // collect totals and save me, if required
    if (1 == $this->getData('trigger_recollect')) {
        $this->collectTotals()->save();
    }
    return parent::_afterLoad();
}
```

Trace of the Loop:

1. The third-party Module [Idev_OneStepCheckout](https://www.onestepcheckout.com/) listen to `sales_quote_collect_totals_before` and Call `Mage::helper('payment')->getStoreMethods($store, $quote)`
2. This Helper Call the method `getConfigData()` by a dynamic Model from the current Payment Methods. Module: Payone_Core
3. `getConfig()` call another [Method](https://github.com/quafzi/payone-magento/blob/master/app/code/community/Payone/Core/Model/Payment/Method/Abstract.php#L368) which trigger the `collectTotals()`

A classic infinity Observer loop.

My first approach was to figure out where Magento set trigger_recollect to 1.

> $ grep -nre "trigger_recollect\|triggerRecollect" --ignore-case

I found this two places:

> app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote.php:207
>   app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Quote.php:282

Magento only call this Methods if you have Catalog Price Rules and change the affected Products. Then all quotes with this Product got the `trigger_recollect` flag. 
But we don't have any Price Rules and the Problem appears for new customer without a existing Quote, too.

Because of this two functions, I'm not longer sure if the specific loop is the result of the flag and this is very frustrating, because I can't explain why the trigger_recollect is set.

All logs (Magento, Nginx, PHP) are empty. Except this message:

> Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

What I also tried was to compare the raw Data of a "normal" Session and a "bad" Session. Both are exactly the same.

A quick and dirty fix would be to rewrite two third party modules, and pass the quote through all method the prevent the `getQuote()` call, but there should be a reason why Magento set the`trigger_recollect` flag or new customer git stuck, too.

Does anybody has a solution or an idea what i can also try or check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

looks like there are a lot more call of the particular methods which changes the `trigger_recollect` flag.
The final solution was to pass the Quote through all methods. The Problem was the result of two third party modules.